# If a Hopf Algebra has a nontrivial, finite-dimensional right ideal, then it is finite dimensional

Tags: hopf-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hopf Algebra (over a field $K$), with comultiplication $\Delta$, counit $\varepsilon$, and antipode $S$.

A $K$-subspace V is said to be:

- A right ideal if $VH \subseteq V$
- A right coideal if $\Delta (V) \subseteq V \otimes H$ (some call this a left coideal...)

Suppose that there is a nonzero right ideal $J$ in $H$, such that $\dim_K (J)$ is finite. Then $\dim_K (H)$ is finite.

The proof breaks in two parts:

1. If $V$ is a nonzero $K$-subspace of a Hopf algebra $H$ that is both a right ideal and a right coideal, then $V=H$.
2. If $J\subseteq H$ is a finite-dimensional, nonzero right ideal of $H$, then $N:= H^* J = \{ f\cdot x = \sum x_{(1)}f(x_{(2)}) : f\in H^* , x\in J\}$ is finite dimensional, nonzero, and it is both a right ideal and a right coideal (thus $H=N$ is finite dimenisonal)

Now, the first part is easy (you prove that there is $x\in V$ such that $\varepsilon (x) = 1$, then $1_H = \varepsilon(x)1_H = \sum x_{(1)}S(x_{(2)}) \in V$).

My problem is the second part. I can prove that $N$ is a finite dimensional subspace: since $J$ is finite dimensional, we can assume it is contained in a finite dimensional subcoalgebra $D$ of $H$; then $N\subseteq D $.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to prove that $N$ is a right ideal and a right coideal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use Sweedler-notation without the sum symbol.

For $h\in{H},f\in{H^*},x\in{J}$ you have:

$m_{(1)}f(m_{(2)})h=m_{(1)}h_{(1)}f(m_{(2)}h_{(2)}S(h_{(3)}))=m_{(1)}h_{(1)}(S(h_{(3)})\rightharpoonup f)(m_{(2)}h_{(2)})=\\(mh_{(1)})_{(1)} (S(h_{(2)}))\rightharpoonup f)(mh_{(1)})_{(2)}\in{N},$

where I used the notation $(a\rightharpoonup g)(b)=g(ba)$.

This shows that $N$ is indeed a right ideal. The proof that $N$ is also a right-coideal should be similiar, maybe this calculation helps you a bit. In fact, $N$ is the right-coideal *generated* by $J$.

Answer (score 1):

A long time passed but I think that this question is still missing an exhaustive answer.

In fact, why $N=H^*\cdot J$ is a right $H$-coideal has not been clarified (even if this is trivial, once you see the trick). All the other parts are treated in detail in the paper [*Integrals for Hopf Algebras*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970672?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by Sweedler.

Consider $H$ as a right $H$-comodule via its own comultiplication $\Delta$: this makes of it a rational left $H^*$-module (essentially by definition) with action $f\cdot h=h_1f(h_2)$. Take a (non-zero) right ideal $J\subseteq H$. Then $H^*\cdot J$ is *the left $H^*$-submodule of $H$ generated by $J$* and, as such, it is rational (see Theorem 2.1.3, part a, in Sweelder's book *Hopf Algebras*).

For the sake of completeness, I will just sketch a direct proof of this claim. Let $C$ be any coalgebra and $N\subseteq M$ a $C^*$-submodule of a rational $C^*$-module $M$. For every $n\in N$ we have that

1. $f\cdot n\in N$ for every $f\in C^*$ because $N$ is a $C^*$-submodule;
2. there exists an element $\sum_{i}m_i\otimes c_i\in M\otimes C$ such that $f\cdot n=\sum_{i}m_if(c_i)$ for every $f\in C^*$ because $n\in M$, which is rational;
3. in 2 we may assume that the $c_i$'s are linearly independent (whence we may consider elements $c_i^*\in C^*$ such that $c_j^*(c_i)=\delta_{i,j}$, the Kronecker's delta).

Now, we may collect together these observations to conclude that for every $j$
$$m_j=\sum_{i}m_ic_j^*(c_i)=c_j^*\cdot n\in N$$
and hence $\sum_{i}m_i\otimes c_i\in N\otimes C$, proving that $N$ is rational as well.